# Wrong indentation in python interpreter after customising interpreter prompts

Tags: python

I have recently made a `usercustomised.py` file as described here (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/appendix.html), which colors my `sys.ps1` and `sys.ps2` attributes as so:

```
import sys

sys.ps1 = "\033[1;33m>>>\033[0m "
sys.ps2 = "\033[1;36m...\033[0m "
```

and added the following line to my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP="*path_to*/usercustomised.py"
```

However, this has now broken the indentation in my python interpreter. Instead of using continuous indents of char size 4, the interpreter now uses one tab of size 1, and another of size 7. For example:

```
>>> for a in A:
...  if line 1:
...         line 2
```

instead of

```
>>> for a in A:
...     if line 1:
...         line 2
```

When I comment out the appropriate line in my `~/.bashrc` file, the interpreter returns to normal with the correct indenting (but now uncoloured, which I don't particularly want).

What is going on? I am using WSL and python 3.7.

Comment: You're mixing up two features, `PYTHONSTARTUP` and `usercustomize.py` (and you spelled `usercustomize.py` wrong).

Comment: `usercustomised.py` is just what I called the file, but can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Also, I doubt your Python was actually using 4-space tabs before. Python's interactive mode doesn't normally do anything special with tabs, so by default, you should get 8-space tab stops. (This is easily mistaken for 4-space tabs with the first tab, but is clearly distinguishable after the second tab on a line.)

Comment: You can call your `PYTHONSTARTUP` file whatever you like - the name you picked is meaningless. `usercustomize.py` is an unrelated feature that lets you set a file that will be run before any invocation of Python by the current user, including non-interactive runs. For that, a specific file name and location are required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should change the settings for that. Look up Python plugins for color schemes. There's plenty out there. I think there will be one close to yours.

Comment: I couldn't find any plugins to customise the prompts, hence why I followed the documentation...